# Can I get a scholarship without a recommendation letter?

Tags: recommendation-letter, international-students

My country is currently on a rough armed conflict, a lot of the official organisations stopped working, I lost contact with my high school’s teachers and I am already abroad now . . . I can’t think of a way to get a recommendation letter, can I apply without one and how to explain my situation??

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot answer that because it is very much dependent on individual factors. A motivation letter explaining your situation might be an idea that could help.

Answer (score 2):

I advise many international students who, for many reasons, cannot get documents from their respective countries. There are several workarounds your issue:

1. Take a class at a local community college (in the US, in other countries, any open-admissions institution) and get a letter from that professor, then ask that professor to write your circumstances on that letter. This might be necessary, for example, if the place you are applying to requires a letter to be uploaded before they'll even look at your application.
2. Go directly to the admissions office at the institution you are applying to, and ask. Some institutions have specific guidelines for working with refugees.
3. Since you mention high school, I assume that you are applying to undergraduate institutions. Find out about high-school equivalency exams in your current country. In the US, this is the GED. You then take the GED classes, and get letters from those teachers.